# When is it acceptable to link to my own SO answers?

Tags: discussion

In the SO community I have a rather narrow niche:  I mainly focus on answering [esapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esapi)[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions because I've got several years of experience coding and mentoring developers on layered application defense, and nearly always with Java.

Since I started answering questions in this niche, I've noticed in some instances that a question I've previously answered is relevant to what I'm discussing.  However, I'm a little leary at linking questions that I've answered myself as it could be construed as spamming to increase traffic to my own answers.  It seems self-promoting in a bad way.

I don't want to even be blamed for something like that.  And I couldn't find a similar question here on Meta.  But I also don't like having to look up my old questions just to dig up and copy the same information into the new question.

What's the best policy here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your answer to question A can be applied to question B, then this is a very good indication that question B is in fact a duplicate of question A. What you should be doing in this case is flagging (as you don't have 3k rep) question B to be closed as a duplicate of question A.

If question B isn't a duplicate then you should be posting a **new self contained** answer to *that* question which is different to your answer on question A, but can reference your original answer.

What we don't want is for people to search for a solution only to be told that the answer is over *there* (even if *there* is still on Stack Overflow).

Comment: What happens often is that questions pop up involving esapi URL validation, which doesn't take into consideration RFC-3986 when it comes up.  So it's kind of like its a two part answer:  Answer the OP with the caveat that *you should know that you'll get unexpected results and here's why.*

Answer (score 3):

If your other answer is really an awesome and **relevant** piece of information, then I would say go ahead and link! True, your content has an advantage over other potential choices, if for no other reason than you are more familiar with it, but if you are *this* concerned about self-promotion, then I think that you would link the other answer if it was truly better.

Now, if an answer would be *entirely* copy-paste, then the question is a duplicate and be closed as such (though this isn't the scenario you described).